# Mailing list with Round Robin assignment

Tags: email, mail-server

Is there a mailing list system that will deliver the message to only one member of the list?

The use case is this:

- suppose you have 5 technicians to do tech support.
- And you receive an email in suppot@mycompany.com
- I want that email to be forwarded to **only one** of the technicians.
- When the next mail arrives it should be assigned to the **next technician** in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [phpList](http://www.phplist.com) may help you in case you want a dedicated system. But is the solution worth the effort?

You can just create local rule in your mail client to forward email accordingly. Say IF the incoming message has certain qualities, THEN it is forwarded to said technician.

Comment: The assignment doesn't depend on anything the email has... it is only when the mail arrives it should be forwarded to the next technician in the queue.